# How to do a set difference, except without eliminating repeated elements

Tags: list, matlab, set-difference

I am trying to do the following in Matlab.  Take two lists of numbers, possibly containing repeated elements, and subtract one set from the other set.

Ex: A=[1 1 2 4]; B=[1 2 4];

Desired result would be A-B=C=[1]

Or, another example, E=[3 3 5 5]; F=[3 3 5];

Desired result would be E-F=G=[5]

I wish I could do this using Matlab's set operations, but their function setdiff does not respect the repeated elements in the matrices.  I appreciate that this is correct from a strict set theory standpoint, but would nevertheless like to tackle problems like: "I have 3 apples and 4 oranges, and you take 2 apples and 1 orange, how many of each do I have left."  My range of possible values in these sets is in the thousands, so building a large matrix for tallying elements and then subtracting matrices does not seem feasible for speed reasons.  I will have to do thousands of these calculations with thousands of set elements during a gui menu operation.

Example of what I would like to avoid for tackling the second example above:
E=[0 0 2 0 2]; F=[0 0 2 0 1];

G=E-F=[0 0 0 0 1];

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Following up on my question some time later... since my largest set size is not totally out of control and huge, I ended up using a matrix based method something along the lines of what prototoast described below.  Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with the accumarray command.

```
A = [1 1 2 4]';
B = [1 2 4]';  % <-make these column vectors

X = accumarray(A, 1);
Y = accumarray(B, 1);
```

This will produce the output

```
X = [2 1 0 1]'
```

and

```
Y = [1 1 0 1]'
```

Where X(i) represents the number of incidents of the number i, in vector A, and Y(i) represents the number of incidents of number i in vector B.

Then you can just take X - Y.

One caveat: if the maximum values of A and B are different, the output from accummarray will have different lengths.  If that is the case, you can just assign the output to be a subset of a vector of zeros that is the size of the larger vector.

Comment: Prototoast, your answer is appreciated and I learned something.  But, I am trying to avoid going to large vectors like this.  I am hoping there is a more efficient sort of set operation or small routine that I could do.

Comment: What is "more efficient"?  You're using Matlab.  Operations on large matrices is what it does _most_ efficiently.  I just did a little test on some 10 million dimensional vectors, and the whole thing took less than a second on my computer.  What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: @prototoast: Careful with potential non-positive values in A or B vectors.

Comment: In addition to being part of my gui, this operation will be a very crucial part of an optimization routine that requires performing it many times quickly.  For this reason, I would prefer to find a different solution.  After your answer yesterday I did try timing a for loop that included many large matrix operations and I do believe them to be fast.  I guess I was just hoping there was something faster I was missing that could exploit the small number of elements in each set.  I'll try using the vector method you recommend and see how it works.  Thanks for your time!

Comment: Sidenote: No negative values are expected

Answer (score 1):

I just want to improve on Prototoast's answer.

In order to avoid pitfalls involving non-positive numbers in **A** or **B** use `hist`:

```
A = [-10 0 1 1 2 4];
B = [1 2 4];
```

We need the minimum and maximum values in the union of **A** and **B**:

```
U = [A,B];
range_ = min(U):max(U);
```

So that we can use `hist` to give us same length vectors:

```
a = hist(A,range_)
b = hist(B,range_)
```

Now you need to subtract the histograms:

```
r = a-b
```

If you wish the set difference operator be symmetric then use:

```
r = abs(a-b)
```

The following will give you which items are in **A** \ **B** (\ here is your modified set difference):

```
C = range_(logical(r))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I should also add that prototoast's answer, when fixed for non-positive values, should work much faster than mine. Function `accumarray` is implemented in C as opposed to `hist` which is in MATLAB.

Comment: Thanks upperbound, I really appreciate it.  No positive values are expected.

Comment: Just for posterity's sake, I wanted to point out that the final step `C = range_(logical(r))` doesn't preserve the number of duplicates found in A.  One possible solution might be to use something like [rude](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6436-rude--a-pedestrian-run-length-decoder-encoder), a run-length decoding function, which worked for me: `C = rude(r, range_);`